# a discrete mathematics problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A(n) be a sentence with one variable defined in the set of all natural numbers N 
then which of the following is true ?

a.-A(0) is valid and if for all n, A(n) is valid then for all n, A(n+1) is valid.

b.-A(n) is true for n=0 and for all natural K, if A(k) is valid for all k < K, then A(K) is also valid.

c.- none

Comment: True? That depends on $A(n)$. As long as we don't know the sentence we cannot judge wether a) or b) is true. BTW what is meant by "...all natural K.."? Is K here a subset of N, or an element?

Comment: @drhab When an OP posts a run-on inequality (using less-than symbol) e.g., `k<K`, **nothing** after the less-than symbol will render. When I spot a question which drops off mid-sentence, I tend to suspect a run-on $<$. To check, just click on the edit link.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you. As you suspected this is indeed new knowledge for me.

Comment: Is the question complete?
option (a) is mathematical induction
option (b) is strong induction or "Complete induction" (as per Wikipedia, that's the term used), a variant of induction,

Answer (score 0):

a is the answer. It is basically the definition of induction.
b is also the correct answer and is exact definition for strong induction.

Comment: (b) is also valid. Check Strong induction. And real numbers are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: ok the question seems to be edited now.

Comment: I am still fairly sure that (b) is strong induction.